# Creating new dataframe with latest NA values by date, while grouped by another column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing various information as below. However, I would like to retrieve the latest (by date) non-NA value of a certain column (Value), while grouped by another column (Team), to be consolidated into a new dataframe.

INPUT:

```
Team    Date             Value        Shape        Value_2
A       2021-01-01       500432       Triangle     123
A       2021-01-02       NA           Triangle     23
A       2021-01-03       NA           Triangle     543
B       2021-01-01       NA           Square       8543
B       2021-01-02       473929       Circle       NA
B       2021-01-03       NA           Circle       356
C       2021-01-01       750830       Rectangle    984
C       2021-01-02       894032       Rectangle    NA
C       2021-01-03       NA           Rectangle    342
```

OUTPUT:

```
Team    Date             Value        Shape
A       2021-01-01       500432       Triangle
B       2021-01-02       473929       Circle
C       2021-01-02       894032       Rectangle
```

Comment: it is much better to provide your data in a ready to use format, e.g. with dput()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A dplyr solution**

We can `group_by` Team, then `arrange` with decreasing Date, `filter` out the NAs from Value, then `slice` the top row per group:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Team) %>%
        arrange(Team, desc(Date)) %>%
        filter(!is.na(Value)) %>%
        slice(1) %>%
        select(-Value_2)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Team [3]
  Team  Date        Value Shape    
  <chr> <date>      <int> <chr>    
1 A     2021-01-01 500432 Triangle 
2 B     2021-01-02 473929 Circle   
3 C     2021-01-02 894032 Rectangle
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
library(data.table)
dt = fread("
Team    Date             Value        Shape        Value_2
A       2021-01-01       500432       Triangle     123
A       2021-01-02       NA           Triangle     23
A       2021-01-03       NA           Triangle     543
B       2021-01-01       NA           Square       8543
B       2021-01-02       473929       Circle       NA
B       2021-01-03       NA           Circle       356
C       2021-01-01       750830       Rectangle    984
C       2021-01-02       894032       Rectangle    NA
C       2021-01-03       NA           Rectangle    342
")

dt[!is.na(Value),tail(.SD,1),by = Team,.SDcols=1:4]
#   Team       Date  Value     Shape
#1:    A 2021-01-01 500432  Triangle
#2:    B 2021-01-02 473929    Circle
#3:    C 2021-01-02 894032 Rectangle
```

- `!is.na(Value)` is to select rows with non-NA `Value`
- `tail(.SD,1)` is to select lates row of each group
- `by = Team` is to group by `Team`
- `.SDcols = 2:4` is to select variables 2:4 (`by = Team` will set `Team` as first column automatically)

Comment: is there anyway to deal with it if I'm sticking to dataframe? I tried your method but it only works for data table.

Comment: I prefer to use `data.table`. It's also a kind of `data frame`. You can set your `df` as `data.table` by `setDT(df)`.